# Spring MVC controller returns null data to the view

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a Controller that returns a list of users.  When users exist, the program works fine.  However, when the user is not found, the controller returns null to the jsp page, in this case, I got a blank screen, none of the "alert" in the jsp page got printed.  Please let me know why the alert("user doesn't exist") cannot be printed and how I handle the situation when the controller returns null to the jsp page.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/userSearch",
                   method = RequestMethod.POST,
                   produces = "application/json")
   @ResponseBody
   public UserList search @RequestParam String username) 
   {     
          UserList userListObj = search(username); // search database

          if (userListObj.getUserList().size() > 0) 
          {
              return userListObj;
          } 
          else 
          {
              return null;
          }
     }
```

JSP code:

```
    function ajaxUserSearch() 
    {   
         var uname = $("#userName").val();
         if ( uname )
         {              
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "userSearch.htm",
                data: "username=" + uname ,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) 
                {   
                     alert("data=" + data);
                     if ( data!=null )
                     {      
                          alert("data not null");
                     } 
                     else 
                     {            
                         alert(" user does not exist, please check");
                     }                 
                },                   
                error: function(jqXHR, status, error)
                {
                    alert("error=" + error + "\nstatus=" + status);
                }              
             });
       }
       else // If no name is entered but Search button is pressed
       {
            alert("Please enter a user name.");
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't return null. Its basically an empty http-reponse.

In the Java code, try to return something like :   `return "notfound"`

And then in the Javacript `success`  try to do something like:

```
if (data != null) {
   if (data === "notfound") {
     alert("user not found"); 
   } else {
      alert("user found" + data);
   }
} else {
   alert("unexpected error when finding user. please try again"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't even a need to check the size of the `userListObj` in your controller... just return the object to the page:

```
@ResponseBody
public UserList search @RequestParam String username) {     
      return search(username); // search database
}
```

Then in your ajax success function, parse the json and check the length of the `UserList`:

```
success: function(data) {   
    var userListObj = $.parseJSON(data);
    if(userListObj.UserList.length > 0) {      
        alert("data not null");
    } else {
        alert("user does not exist, please check");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved my own problem by disabling the enter key on the client input field.

```
  $("form").bind("keypress", function (event) 
            {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) 
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```